# SpringBoot's DataJpaTest with Flyway

Tags: mysql, testing, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, flyway

I'm using flyway in my project to setup the DB schema. When I try using the @DataJpaTest annotation to test some JPA layer I get this error upon startup:

```
> Caused by:
> org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateSqlException:
> Migration V1__init.sql failed
> ----------------------------- SQL State  : 42581 Error Code : -5581 Message    : unexpected token: AUTO_INCREMENT : line: 2 Location   :
> db/migration/V1__init.sql
> ..../target/classes/db/migration/V1__init.sql) Line       : 1
> Statement  : CREATE TABLE mytable (    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
> PRIMARY KEY,
```

It looks like it is trying to use HSQL instead of the regular SQL

Is there a way I can use @DataJpaTest with flyway ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's trying to use [HSQLDB](http://javasampleapproach.com/testing/datajpatest-with-spring-boot) to execute the scripts. What you can do is create a database schema for tests and use it in a different profile. Assuming that you're using MySQL, you could have an `application-test.properties` inside your resources source folder like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_db
spring.datasource.username=your_user
spring.datasource.password=your_pass
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

And then, in your test class you need to activate this profile with the annotation `@ActiveProfiles` and disable HSQLDB with the annotation config in `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase`:

```
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
public class DBTest { ... }
```

Comment: I still get the same error (flyway still tried to execute my migration scripts with HSQLDB)

Comment: Is your `application-test.properties` inside `src/main/resources`?